# Issue in running nodes in different machine using public ip address

Tags: corda

I am using Azure to run Corda. I am running two VMs which have private/internal and public IP addresses.

The Corda nodes can connect to each other using the private/internal IP addresses, but when I try to connect the nodes using the public IP addresses they fail to connect.

Comment: Can you please provide additional details on the VMs (cloud provider, etc.)?

Comment: i have created two VM's in Microsoft Azure. Both VM's has private (like 10.2.5.1 & 10.2.5.2) *Example IP and public IP address( like 53.112.23.14 and 13.1.111.12)  *Example IP respectively

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check that the "firewall" rules applied by the Network Security Group allow access to the ports on which you are running Corda.

Go to the Virtual Machines blade, select one of your VMs, and then click the Networking tab. Click the "Effective security rules" link and see whether traffic would be allowed through on the port you've configured as the p2pAddress in node.conf.

If the traffic would not be allowed, you need to add an Inbound rule to the Network Security Group, e.g.:

Source: Any
Source port ranges: *
Destination: Any
Destination port ranges:  10002 (or your p2pAddress port in node.conf)
Protocol: TCP
Action: Allow
Priority: (higher than any existing rules)

Comment: Got it Ben. Thanks:)